# Eigenvalues of a specific $9\times9$ matrix - a simpler way?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $ρ$ be the permutation of $\{1, \dots , 9\}$ be given by $$ρ=\bigg(\begin{array}  \\1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \\2 3 4 1 6 7 5 9 8 \end{array}\bigg)$$ and let $α : C^9 → C^9$ be the linear map defined
>   by by $α(e_j) = e_{ρ(j)}$, $j = 1, \dots , 9$. What are the
>   eignevalues of $α$?

I know how to find them directly, but I was wondering, if there's a way of doing it without calculating characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Writing $\rho$ in cycle form seems like a good idea. $\rho=(1234)(567)(89)$, so its matrix is block-diagonal with blocks corresponding to the three cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute the characteristic polynomial is not that difficult in this case: if you draw the matrix of $\alpha$, you'll see that it's a block-diagonal matrix, with three blocks along the main diagonal. So the characteristic polynomial is the product of the characteristic polynomials of these blocks, which are

$$
t^2-1 \ , \quad -t^3 + 1 \quad \text{and}\quad t^4 -1 \ .
$$

Comment: You're welcome.  :-)